# Analogue input 0 staying at 0 when sensing light with Arduino and a photocell

Tags: sensors, hardware, prototype, analog-sampling, photoresistor

I am doing a circuit for capturing light intensities.

I followed the [tutorial provided by Adil Moujahid](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2015/07/practical-introduction-iot-arduino-nodejs-plotly/)

Yet, when I plug the jumper wires on 5V the circuit stops working and when I plug on 3.3V the analog in A0 sent back only a series of zero...

What did I missed? I acknowledge that I tried to be the most economical on the jumper wires...

## The sketches, program and circuit given by Adil Mouhajid

[image: The program]

[image: The circuit provided by the site]

## My attempt

[image]

Comment: While the code is not relevant to your issue here, in the future please place your code text into the question directly, instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: `What did I missed? I acknowledge that I tried to be the most economical on the jumper wires.` - that's what you missed. The bottom two lines are connected **horizontally** (all the way along) - thus you just shorted everything together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two strips on either side of the bread board, color red and blue (typically) are power rails, and each strip is all connected. Your circuit connections that are on that strip are shorted together and will not work. I suggest following his layout exactly to begin with, and once you've learned the basics of breadboard connections, you can start doing your own layouts.